# JComboBox take priority before Keyboard shortcut

Tags: jcombobox, shortcut

I added some keyboard shortcuts in java, and most of the time they are working as expected. 
Only in case the focus is inside comboBox, and the combobox contains values that start with the shortcut, then pressing the key change the combobox value, and not running the action.

In the following example, I want that pressing 1/2 will always call button1/button2, but instead it is changing the values in the combo.

Is there any simple way to change this behavior?

[image]

+Note that I tried to setup the 3 parameter in function registerKeyboardAction 
instead:

```
JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW
```

to:

```
JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT
```

That didn't helped.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class TestCombo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEST");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"});

        panel.add(comboBox);

        JButton button1 = new JButton(new TextAction("Text1"));
        JButton button2 = new JButton(new TextAction("Text2"));

        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);

        panel.registerKeyboardAction(button1.getAction(), KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, false), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        panel.registerKeyboardAction(button2.getAction(), KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_2, 0, false), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


    private static class TextAction extends AbstractAction{

        private String text;

        public TextAction(String vText){
            text = vText;
            putValue(Action.NAME, text);
        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched other posts and currently didn't find best solution for this, but as workaround I found the option to add some prefix in the combobox value (e.g. space before each value). This way the shortcuts are working. Of course the issue is that you won't be able to use the keys to search the combobox values. But in my case it is what I wanted.

```
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{" 1", " 2", " 3", " 4", " 5"});
```